# Windows XP recovery console crashes

Tags: windows-xp, crash, recovery, recovery-console

A computer on our CNC machines has Windows XP, and it gave the classic:

```
\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CONFIG\SYSTEM is missing or corrupt
```

So I took the install disk (Windows XP Professional), put it into the CD-ROM, and it starts.

But when I press <kbd>R</kbd> to recover and it then asks me on which disk I should have the recovery:

```
1:C:\WINDOWS
```

After I type 1 and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of showing the administrator password input the screen just stands still...it crashes.

What can I do? Factory settings are out of the question as I have the CNC router data and programming on it.

Comment: Check the drive's health to start with something. The symptom suggest it failed or is about to fail. Either way you have to start from a fresh installation in a new drive. And you should have upgrade the OS a long time ago if it's working in a network even without access to the exterior (internet). Windows XP is missing some 8 years of security updates.

Answer (score 0):

The `system32\config\SYSTEM` file contains a large part of the Windows system's *registry,* specifically the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System` branch. If that file is missing, a large part of your OS configuration is gone with it – including its knowledge about all the drivers, services, and other system-wide components that were installed as part of your CNC software.

Most likely all the program and data *files* are still there, so you could retrieve them for the new install if necessary – but I'm not sure if the whole OS can be recovered, at least not in a "working" state. I'd suggest you image the failed disk, do a fresh install of the OS and the CNC software, then try to gather your specific configuration out of the old disk (e.g. from Program Files or AppData) to place at the right locations on the new one.

Comment: In other words...The installation is likely toast and beyond repair.  I would agree this is the  install a new HDD into the system and restore my working configuration

Comment: This is problematic, but I'll give it a try and report back to you.
Thank you very much for the insightful answer.